# Apache Shiro: Wildcard permission is not working

Tags: apache, shiro

The wildcard for the Apache Shiro is not working

Tried several steps with isPermitted

Dear all,

I´m using Apache Shiro (version 1.4.1). For a single permission everything is fine, but if I would like to use wildcard permission it´s not working. Why?

I have for example:
customer:create
customer:delete
customer:showAll

If I´m using:
`shiroUser.isPermitted("customer:create")`, than it´s working.

But:

```
shiroUser.isPermitted("customer:*"), is NOT working...
```

Is there any settings which I have to enable for it?

I have currently no idea why it´s not working...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I always think about it the other way around.  I grant my users the more flexible version of the permission i.e. `customer:*`, and I always check for specific permission: `customer:create`.

Taking a step back, can you explain your use case a bit more and maybe we could offer a suggestion on what you should try.